# How to evaluate DynamoDB metrics to decide WCU/RCU limits for a Provisioned Capacity Mode Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

Recently, I'm considering to switch some of my DynamoDB on-demand tables to Provisioned capacity mode to save cost. I'm planning to enable autoscaling for WCU and RCU, But I'm confused about DynamoDB and CloudWatch relation. To be able to decide Write Capacity Unit and Read Capacity Unit min/max values in autoscaling, I'm examining CloudWatch metrics to find out these values but it's quite confusing to find a methodology. AWS saying in this documentation that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html

```
Sum – The total write capacity units consumed. This is the most useful statistic for the ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits metric.
Sum – The total read capacity units consumed. This is the most useful statistic for the ConsumedReadCapacityUnits metric.
```

But when I try to edit my table to change it from On-Demand to Provisioned, there is an explanation like below
[image: explanation is here]

and, when I clicked on `View in CloudWatch metrics`, statistic is shown as `Average`

[image: View in CloudWatch metrics screenshot]

My question is, which CloudWatch statistic and period should be used to be sure how much resources my table is consuming so that I can decide min and max WCU/RCU consumption boundaries of the table to not face any throttling.

Answer (score 2):

The only useful piece of data I would add here is that DynamoDB averages your RCUs and WCUs over a 5-minute period (not sure where I read it, but somebody may correct me), so your reads and writes can spike as long as the total number of units consumed over the 5-min window is less than the provisioned capacity.  (Please also note the [definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html) of RCU/WCU in terms of volume of data and read-consistency, if you are not familiar with it.)

From here, it is up to you to decide how far into the past your history can represent your future, if it indeed can, because this is a philosophical question.